# passing one image from batch to function in c++

Tags: c++, tensorflow2.x, tensorflow-c++

I'm trying to change a code in this repo from 2D to 3D; https://github.com/sadeepj/crfasrnn_keras

However, my C++ is super rusty and I'm having a hard time with one problem.
I'm trying to pass the Tensor& out to this function;

```
void ModifiedPermutohedral::compute(Tensor& out, const Tensor& in, int value_size, bool reverse, bool add) const
```

with this line

```
ModifiedPermutohedral mp;
const Tensor& input_tensor = context->input(0);
Tensor* output_tensor = NULL;
OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(0, input_tensor.shape(), &output_tensor));
mp.compute(output_tensor->SubSlice(b), input_tensor.SubSlice(b), channels, backwards_);
```

where b is the batch index I want to pass to this compute function. However, it gives me an error that

```
error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘tensorflow::Tensor&’ to an rvalue of type ‘tensorflow::Tensor’
```

I believe it's because output_tensor is a pointer, but how am I supposed to pass it then? Shouldn't the SubSlice function return a tensor? I've tried

```
&(output_tensor->SubSlice(b))
*(output_tensor->SubSlice(b))
```

too but all creates a different error. Can anyone provide insights on how I should pass this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am not familiar with tensorflow C++, I noticed that in `mp.compute(output_tensor->SubSlice(b), input_tensor.SubSlice(b), channels, backwards_);`, first argument is a rvalue such that which cannot be used for value assigning purpose. I suggest:

```
auto sliced_putput = output_tensor->SubSlice(b);
mp.compute(sliced_output, input_tensor.SubSlice(b), channels, backwards_);
//Assign sliced output to the output_tensor's appropriate dimensiton
```

Comment: The file worked without error! I'm not sure this will solve everything but at least it solved one of my problems. Thank you very much :)